# How to add Toolbar in PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, toolbar, preferenceactivity

I have created an app settings with Preferences.
But I noticed, that there no toolbar in my PreferenceActivity.
How I can add toolbar to my PreferenceActivity?

My code:

my pref_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListPreference
    android:key="select_class"
    android:title="@string/select_class"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:entries="@array/classy"
    android:entryValues="@array/classy"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/select_class" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

my PrefActivity.java:

```
package ***.***.***;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefFragment()).commit();
}

public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
    }
}
}
```

P.S Gautam, at your .java code there's an error in the line:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); :

     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx/xxx.PrefActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
                                                                             at com.smartfon_apps.timetable_sch32.PrefActivity.onCreate(PrefActivity.java:21)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: use preference fragment with appcompatactivity and include toolbar in your activity layout

Comment: you cant set toolbar in activity layout? how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an activity extending AppCompatActivity containing your toolbar referenced from layout file like below

```
public class UserSettingPreference extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                onBackPressed();

        }
    });
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new UserPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

}
```

Define your layout containing a toolbar and a framelayout to hold the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Toolbar 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then define your fragment extending preference fragment like below -

```
public class UserPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
```

To refer to your preference.xml override onCreate of fragment like below -

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_preference);
}
```

To refer particular elements inside your preference.xml use getPreferenceScreen method

```
switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("floating_widget");
```

Comment: `layout_below` is not required in `Linear Layout`

Comment: And where iis my pref.xml?

Comment: see my updated answer. If it works for you please accept the answer :)

Comment: @Gautam switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("floating_widget");

Comment: since you are using ListPreference then change it accordingly. I mentioned it just for reference. You can use it like ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("select_class"); inside onCreate. It behaves likes findViewById method

Comment: @Gautam, ok. But in     toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(LibUiConstants.TOOLBAR_BG_COLOR));

Comment: You can remove that line or you can use any custom color like #ff0000 for red color. Its used for changing the toolbar color